# knitr error compiling child rnw from within child rnw

Tags: r, knitr

I have a working project folder structure as follows:

```
project/
         report/
                multiple-calls.rnw
                section/
                        call1.rnw
         support/
                 call2.rnw
```

I call the child document `call1.rnw` from within the main document `multiple-calls.rnw`. I am trying to call `call2.rnw` from within `call1.rnw`. Given that the working directly resets to the home directory of the main `.rnw` file, I would think I can call `call2.rnw` from within `call1.rnw` using:

```
<<child-call2, child="../support/call2.rnw", eval=TRUE>>=
@
```

But I receive an error:

```
In readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { :
  cannot open file './section/../support/call2.rnw': No such file or directory
```

I am sure I had this working before, but for some reason it does not seem to compile now.

I have tried many variations of `./` and `../../` but it still does not work.

The documentation link is [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/), seems the idea should work but not sure I am missing something simple!

The sample project folder with files can be cloned from `github` using

`https://github.com/scottprevost/knitr-multiple-child-rnw.git`

Any help is appreciated!